# Thunderbird & Unity integration

Tags: unity, 13.04, thunderbird

How do I get thunderbird & unity integration, specially the icon on the top bar? its raring ringtail btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some things I tried, when I could not get Unity and Thunderbird integrated.

Please check to see that global menu is installed. 
You can run `sudo apt-get install thunderbird-globalmenu` to get a message that it is installed, or it will be installed.

You can also try uninstalling and re-installing Thunderbird.

You could also try this: try removing the Thunderbird version that is currently installed. and add the ppa provided by mozilla team using

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa`

The Thunderbird menu will take over the top menu.

Comment: well I already had that package installed, althougth I removed and installed it again but still not docked on the menu. Im concern about removing/installing thunderbird from scratch , I 've a lot of mailing and account settings.

Comment: Edited OP with one more thing to try.